# How to perform asynchronous data transfer over SSH channel in JSch

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, jsch

I want to perform bitwise asynchronous data transfer over an SSH channel created through JSch. For asynchronous transfer, I am intending to use two threads, one for receiving and another for sending data. How to acheive this?
Following is the best code i could come up with but it is having inheritance problems...

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyThread extends Thread
{
    String name;
  private PipedInputStream pin;
  private PipedOutputStream pout;
  Queue q_manager_to_server = new LinkedList();
  Queue q_server_to_manager = new LinkedList();  
  int data;
  int temp;

  MyThread (String name, PipedInputStream pin, PipedOutputStream pout)
  {
   super (name);
   this.name = name;
   this.pin = pin;
   this.pout = pout;
  }

  public void run ()
  {
   try
   {
       System.out.print("Starting thread : "+name);
     if (getName ().equals ("to_server"))
     {
       try{
           while(true){
               data = (byte)pin.read();
               System.out.println("Received : "+data);
               q_manager_to_server.offer(data);
               temp = (int)q_manager_to_server.poll();
               if (temp != 0){
                System.out.print("Sending : "+temp);
               pout.write(temp);
               }
           }
       }
         catch(Exception e){
             pout.close();
         }
     }
     else
     {
      // while ((item = pin.read ()) != -1)
      //  System.out.print ((char) item);    // dst reads
       System.out.print("Starting thread : "+name);      
         try{
           while(true){
               data = (byte)pin.read();
               System.out.println("Received : "+data);
               q_server_to_manager.offer(data);
               temp = (int)q_server_to_manager.poll();
               if (temp != 0){
                System.out.print("Sending : "+temp);
               pout.write(temp);
           }
         }
         }
           catch(Exception e){
             pout.close();
           }
     }
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
   }
  }
}

public class ARDAS_manager{
  public static void main(String[] arg){

    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();

      //jsch.setKnownHosts("/home/foo/.ssh/known_hosts");

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@localhost"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 2200);

      String passwd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter password");
      session.setPassword(passwd);

      UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo(){
        public void showMessage(String message){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
        }
        public boolean promptYesNo(String message){
          Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
          int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                                               message,
                                               "Warning", 
                                               JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                               JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                               null, options, options[0]);
          return foo==0;
        }

      };

      session.setUserInfo(ui);

      // It must not be recommended, but if you want to skip host-key check,
      // invoke following,
      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

      //session.connect();
      session.connect();   // making a connection with timeout.

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
      // Creating PipedStreams

      PipedOutputStream pout_server=new PipedOutputStream();  
      PipedInputStream pin_server=new PipedInputStream();

      PipedOutputStream pout_manager=new PipedOutputStream();  
      PipedInputStream pin_manager=new PipedInputStream();

      pout_manager.connect(pin_server);  
      pout_server.connect(pin_manager);   

      channel.setInputStream(pin_server);
      channel.setOutputStream(pout_manager);

      channel.connect(3*1000);

      //channel.wait(10);

      MyThread manager_to_server = new MyThread ("to_server", pin_manager, pout_server);
      MyThread server_to_manager = new MyThread ("to_manager", pin_server, pout_manager);
/*    Thread manager_to_server = new Thread(){
          public void run(){
              while (true){
                  try{
                  pout.write();
                  }
                  catch(){
                      System.out.println("[-]Error in sending data");
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      Thread server_to_manager = new Thread(){
          public void run(){
              while (true){
                  try{
                  pin.read();
              }
              catch(){
                  System.out.println("[-]Error in receiving data");
              }
              }
          }
      }

    */
      System.out.print("I am Here!!!");
      manager_to_server.setDaemon(false);
      manager_to_server.start ();
      manager_to_server.join ();      

      server_to_manager.setDaemon (false);      
      server_to_manager.start ();
      /*
      // a hack for MS-DOS prompt on Windows.
      channel.setInputStream(new FilterInputStream(System.in){
          public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)throws IOException{
            return in.read(b, off, (len>1024?1024:len));
          }
        });
       */

      //channel.connect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static abstract class MyUserInfo
                          implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){ return false; }
    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return false; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){ return false; }
    public void showMessage(String message){ }
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What problem are you facing? What data are you transferring?

Comment: I have successfully opened a channel to remote device but dont know how to transfer asynchronous data seamlessly and continuously in java. Data has to be bitwise continuous streams. Following is the code , it is having some inheritance problems...

Comment: What makes you believe that JSch session is thread-safe in the first place?

Comment: After opening a session, a channel is opened for end to end communication. For asynchronous communication, two threads can be used, for sending and receiving purpose. Threads are inbuilt feature of OS and has nothing to do with API being used. Secondly, here simple data relay is to be done that can hardly make the program behave abruptly.

Comment: But you access the same instance of the `Channel` class from both threads. Did you find any claim that the `Channel` class is thread safe?

Comment: *For asynchronous communication, two threads can be used, for sending and receiving purpose* - Who says that?

Comment: Yeah.. I modified the code and now I am using PipedInputStream, as I found that this class in specific for the threads that want to communicate. But what other way do one has to perform asynchronous receiving and sending simultaneously but two use two threads... In code, I am still unable to make successful data transfer. I have created two streams each for both devices ( A server and a manager). Each stream specific for either receiving or sending and have set the Input and Output streams of the channel. Still i am unable to perform bi way asynchronous comm.